# Make ":w" command throw an error on filenames starting with a colon ":"

Tags: command-line, save, filenames

From time to time I accidentally create files with names like ":w" or ":q". This happens when instead of writing `:wq` I type `:w:q` and sometimes, for some reason, even `:w:w` or `:w :w`. And this has become too frequent to ignore.

My solution to this problem would be to make vim throw an error if `:w` is given a filename that starts with a colon. Are there ways to force vim to behave like that? Or maybe there is another obvious solution I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disallow writing files matching `:*` pattern (no matter which command is used):

```
autocmd BufWritePre :* throw "Invalid name"
```

Comment: Such comments will probably be deleted, but just wanted to confirm that this works and is doing exactly what I wanted. On top of that files that contain `:` are allowed, and only the ones starting with `:` show the error. Perfect, thank you.

Comment: Why would it be deleted? :-) Thanks for the feedback and thanks to @Matt for the perfect solution :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I think it's SO policy to delete simple "thank you" comments. BTW thanks for your answer as well - but I really wanted it to be an error, so then it would force me to notice it happened and maybe stop doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I would introduce an abbreviation:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> :w (getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdline() =~ '^w\s*') ? '' : ':w'
```

With this abbreviation if you type `:w` in the command line (`getcmdtype() == ':'`) that match `w\s*` (`getcmdline() =~ '^w\s*'`) it is abbreviated as '' and the not wanted extra `:w` are removed.